# how join laravel tables to get non intersected data

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join, eloquent

in my `Laravel` app I have 3 tables : `users`, `documents` and `type_documents`, the user have multiple documents and document have one type_document

```
| Documents       | 
| --------        |
| id              | 
| file            | 
| type_document_id| 
| user_id         | 

| type_documents | 
| --------       |
| id             | 
| name           | 

| users          | 
| --------       |
| id             | 
| name           | 
| type_document_d|
```

I want select the types that are not used in `documents` table for the current user with `eloquent` 
I try with this, but it give me the used type_documents :

```
$document_types = TypeDocument::leftJoin('docments' , function ($join) {
                    $join->on('type_documents.id', '=', 'douments.type_document_id')
                         ->where('documents.user_id', auth()->id());
                })
                ->applyFilters($request->all())
                ->latest()
                ->paginateData($limit);
```

I use Laravel version 8

Comment: Did you define the relation method between TypeDocument and User Models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried whereNotExists() or whereNotIn() instead of leftJoin()?

eg:

```
<?php
// whereNotIn
$types = TypeDocument::whereNotIn('id', function($query) {
    $query->select('type_document_id')
          ->from('documents')
          ->where('user_id', auth()->id);
})->get();
```

```
<?php
// whereNotExists
$types = TypeDocument::whereNotExists(function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
          ->from('documents')
          ->whereRaw('type_documents.id = documents.type_document_id')
          ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```

```
<?php
// leftJoin
$types = TypeDocument::leftJoin('documents', function($join) {
    $join->on('type_documents.id', '=', 'documents.type_document_id')
         ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
})->whereNull('documents.type_document_id')->get();
```

try any of these!

Comment: Thanks the first solution with `whereNotIn` works  fine :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Eloquent relation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) defined between `TypeDocument::class` and `User::class` like this:

TypeDocument.php

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'documents', 'type_document_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('file');
}
```

The you can easily get the type document not linked to a specific user like this

```php
TypeDocument::whereDoesntHave('users', function($userQuery) {
        $userQuery->where('users.id', '=', auth()->id());
    })  
    ->applyFilters($request->all())
    ->latest()
    ->paginateData($limit);
```

--------------**EDIT**--------------

IF you want to use two step relation, you can define it like this:

TypeDocument.php

```php
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
}
```

Document.php

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And use the relations to query it like this:

```php
TypeDocument::whereDoesntHave('documents.user', function($userQuery) {
        $userQuery->where('users.id', '=', auth()->id());
    })  
    ->applyFilters($request->all())
    ->latest()
    ->paginateData($limit);
```

Comment: It's not many to many relationship, There is no relationship between typ_document and user

Comment: @MAHAOUEGHLANI The structure you have is of a many to many relation. two tables with ID and another pivot table with TWO foreign IDs to two other tables. it's the definition of pivot table. either way, the relation should work regardless. you can also define two step relations, Has many and belongs to instead.

Comment: @MAHAOUEGHLANI the difference between using relations and erhan's solution is that it runs only one query with joins instead of 2 query with one nested.

Comment: I've already defined your second solution (with 2 relations) and it works also thank you for your explication :)

Comment: oui klemek shih ama b logique un user gére des documents non pas des typed_document heka3leh khdemtHa hekek ken na3melha pivot ma3ach nefhemha tdakhalni ba3dhi

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```php
TypeDocument::whereNotIn('id', function($query){

    $query->select('type_document_id')
    ->from(with(new Documents)->getTable())
    ->where('type_document_id', $query->id)
    ->where('user_id', auth()->id());
        
})->get();
```

Comment: I got `undefined property id` in ` ->where('type_document_id', $query->id)`